# Error when creating AKS cluster using a reference for the subnet ID

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-resource-manager, azure-aks

I'm getting an error when I try to deploy an AKS cluster using an ARM template, if the vnetSubnetId in the agentPoolProfiles property is a reference. I've used this exact template before without problems (on October 4th) but now I'm seeing an error with multiple different clusters, and when I do it either through a VSTS pipeline, or manually using PowerShell.

The property is set up like this:

```
"agentPoolProfiles": [
  {
    "name": "agentpool",
    "count": "[parameters('agentCount')]",
    "vmSize": "[parameters('agentVMSize')]",
    "osType": "Linux",
    "dnsPrefix": "[variables('agentsEndpointDNSNamePrefix')]",
    "osDiskSizeGB": "[parameters('agentOsDiskSizeGB')]",
    "vnetSubnetID": "[reference(concat('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', variables('vnetName'))).subnets[0].id]"
  }
]
```

The variable 'vnetName' is based on an input parameter I use for the cluster name, and the vnet itself 100% exists, and is deployed as part of the same template.

If I try to deploy a new cluster I get the following error:

```
Message: {
  "code": "InvalidParameter",
  "message": "The value of parameter agentPoolProfile.vnetSubnetID is invalid.",
  "target": "agentPoolProfile.vnetSubnetID"
 }
```

If I try to re-deploy a cluster, with no changes to the template or input parameters since it last worked, I get the following error:

```
Message: {
  "code": "PropertyChangeNotAllowed",
  "message": "Changing property 'agentPoolProfile.vnetSubnetID' is not allowed.",
  "target": "agentPoolProfile.vnetSubnetID"
 }
```

Has something changed that means I can no longer get the vnet ID at runtime? Does it need to be passed in as a parameter now? If something has changed, is there anywhere I can find out the details?

Edit: Just to clarify, for re-deploying a cluster, I have checked and there are no new subnets, and I'm seeing the same behavior on 3 different clusters with different VNets.

Switching from reference() to resourceId() did fix the problem so has been marked as the answer, but I'm still no clearer on why reference() stopped working, will update that here as well if I figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what happened is `subnets[0].id` returns wrong (**DIFFERENT**) subnetId. and this is what the error points out. You cannot change the subnetId after deploying the cluster.

Probably somebody created a new subnet in the vnet. But I'd say that overall the approach is flawed. you should build the `resourceId()` function or just pass it as a parameter

Comment: It definitely doesn't point to the wrong subnet, and as I mentioned it also gives an error for a new cluster. When you say build the resourceId() - what do you mean? I'd rather not pass it in as a parameter, as then we'd have to have the vnet in a separate template. More than anything, I'm concerned that this behavior has changed so suddenly, as it worked fine last week.

Comment: impossible to tell you what is wrong with your template without looking at the whole template. i've never seen breaking changes in arm templates, so its 99.999% your side

Comment: Just tried using resourceId() and I have the same problem.

Comment: you tried vnetId, not subnetId, which again, confirms what I said

Comment: Sorry yes, I did spot that and I'm trying to test resourceId properly now. However, I just tried hard-coding the vnetSubnetId with what it currently is, and it worked correctly. I also included the original reference function in the outputs of the template, and it matches exactly with what I hardcoded in the template - so it definitely seems as though reference isn't working properly.

Comment: either way, you should `reseourceId()` function for that, not `reference()` function, fix your template to uses proper function and it will work. to tell what is exactly wrong with your template, I'd need to look at it

Comment: Using resourceId() did the trick, thanks for the help. I'm still confused about why reference() worked previously and not today when the template, parameters, & subnets hadn't changed, but happy it's working now.